# SwiftUI how to refactor list item into a subview

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have been trying to create smaller reusable view for a simple SwiftUI project. However, I'm getting unexpected results and struggling to understand why.

Here is my contrived example to highlight the issue

**Using this example, how should you create a reusable *RowView* to take place of the `HStack` in a list**

```
var body: some View {
    List(vm.gradings) { item in
        // how should you refactor out this ??
        HStack {
            Text(item.grade)
            Text(item.pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Firebase to trigger a model change. i.e changing a grade to pass or fail and expecting the list detail view to display that change.

The above method works as expected, while on the list view and the row will change when the data is changed.

However, when I try and refactor that view out, only one works as expected. Ideally, I'd like to pass in the `Grading` object, but that doesn't cause the view to refresh.

Trying different subviews and their results

```
var body: some View {
    List(vm.gradings) { item in

        // Works
        RowA(grade: item.grade, pass: item.pass)

        // Fails
        // RowB(item: item)

        // Fails
        // RowC(item: item)

        // Default - works as expected
        // HStack {
        //  Text(item.grade)
        //  Text(item.pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
        // }
    }
}
```

Here are the 3 row options

```
// Works
struct RowA: View {
    var grade: String
    var pass: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(grade)
            Text(pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
        }
    }
}

// Fails
struct RowB: View {
    var item: Grading

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(item.grade)
            Text(item.pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
        }
    }
}

// Fails
struct RowC: View {
    @State var item: Grading

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(item.grade)
            Text(item.pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
        }
    }
}
```

*Work Around*

```
// Allows me to pass in just the model
struct RowD: View {
    private var item = Grading()
    private var grade: String = ""
    private var pass: Bool = false

    init(item: Grading) {
        self.item = item
        self.grade = item.grade
        self.pass = item.pass
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(grade)
            Text(pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
        }
    }
}
```

**My view model**

```
class StudentGradingsUIViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var detailedstudent: DetailedStudent

    var gradings: [Grading] {
        detailedstudent.student.gradings
    }

    init(student: DetailedStudent) {
        self.detailedstudent = student
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a @state, I found all what you are doing is right at least in these View portion.

```
       / Works
        struct RowA: View {
            var grade: String
            var pass: Bool

            var body: some View {
                HStack {
                    Text(grade)
                    Text(pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
                }
            }
        }

        //// Fails
        struct RowB: View {
            var item: Grading

            var body: some View {
                HStack {
                    Text(item.grade)
                    Text(item.pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
                }
            }
        }
        //
        //// Fails
        struct RowC: View {
            @State var item: Grading

            var body: some View {
                HStack {
                    Text(item.grade)
                    Text(item.pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
                }
            }
        }

        struct  Grading: Identifiable{
            var id = UUID()
            var grade : String
            var pass  : Bool
        }

        struct TempGradingView: View {

            @State var gradings: [Grading] = [Grading.init(grade: "50", pass: false),Grading.init(grade: "100", pass: true),Grading.init(grade: "100", pass: true)]


        var body: some View {
            Group{
            Button("change", action: {
                self.gradings[0].grade = "70"
            })
            List(gradings) { item in

                // Works
               // RowA(grade: item.grade, pass: item.pass)

                // Fails
                 RowB(item: item)

                // Fails
                // RowC(item: item)

                // Default - works as expected
                // HStack {
                //  Text(item.grade)
                //  Text(item.pass ? "Pass" : "Fail")
                // }
                }}
        }
        }
```

So I think the problematic part, i.e. @publisher var. part.

Comment: Ideally I'd like just to pass the item. I did find a sorta hack way to pass in just the model and get it to refresh - ill post that

Comment: You need @publisher / and observable objects.

Comment: I have those - I guess just not set up ideally

Answer (score 0):

This works - wondering I think its a decent approach

```
private func gradingRow(_ grading: Grading) -> some View {
    HStack {
        Text(grading.grade)
            .foregroundColor(grading.pass ? Color(UIColor.systemGreen) : Color(UIColor.systemRed))
        Spacer()
        Text(DateString.dateAsDDMMYYTime(from: grading.date))
            .font(.subheadline)
    }
}
```